# How to update/import daily IAP in android and ios?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

I am new to IAP (in-app purchases) and I am using Flutter in order to do this for both Android and iOS, my question is as I want to build a dynamic products/books for my bookshop, which mean I want to be able to update/change/import new price and products/book as the price have been changed. So, far I have learned that the best case is that I have to upload my products using CSV file inside Android Play Console for example, but this is not a good option as I have to do it manually and it will not work as my prices change all the time, even the author of the book can change the price and because I am new to this, **can you tell me what is the best way to deal with this situation** as I know that Google always gives the example of Aliexpress which are using Flutter for there app, but they have millions of products are the too uploading every second an CVS file, I hardly believe that.

Comment: Are these physical books or electronic books delivered in the app?  For physical goods (which is what aliexpress sells) you cannot use in app purchase, you use some external payment gateway, like Stripe. For Ebooks you will need some sort of virtual credit system. The user purchases credits and then redeems some number of the for the books.  By changing the number of credits you set the effective price for the books. On iOS adding a new IAP requires a new version is submitted to the App Store and reviewed. A credit system avoids this as your IAPs don't change; they are just credit bundles

Comment: @Paulw11, thank you very much for your command, that answers all my question. I need this for both physical and e-books. This I think is the best solution! You are right about AliExpress, but what about for example Udemy which has a lot of courses and they add new ones daily, then upload a new version and add IAP's every day?

Comment: Please post that as answer, thanks!